# Show the convergence of $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{2}\cdot \frac{(2n)!}{n!(n+1)!}\cdot \left(\frac{1}{4}\right)^n$

Tags: sequences-and-series

As stated by the prompt, I'm looking to show the convergence of the series $$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{2}\cdot \frac{(2n)!}{n!(n+1)!}\cdot \left(\frac{1}{4}\right)^n$$
I've tried using the ratio, root, and Limit Comparison test (w/ a geometric series), and all have given me inconclusive answers.  If anyone has some insights for how I might be able to show this series converges, your help would be much appreciated.

Comment: You can simplify your exptession or it is $(2n)!.

Comment: Have you tried Stirling Formula.

Comment: @hamam_Abdallah it is $(2n)!$, and I hadn't thought to use Stirling's approximation for the factorial, that might be a good route for me to explore.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One possible solution using [Raabe's Test](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/RaabesTest.html)
$$n\cdot\left(\frac{a_n}{a_{n+1}} -1\right) = n\cdot\frac{6n +6}{(2n+1)(2n+2)}\to \frac{3}{2}>1$$

Comment: That will do it for me, thank you!  @J.G.'s answer was great and slick, but I think this will work better given the audience this proof would be written for.  Thank you again

Answer (score 2):

[In fact](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalan_number#First_proof), if $|x|\le\tfrac14$ then $\sum_{n\ge0}\frac{(2n)!}{n!(n+1)!}x^n=\frac{1-\sqrt{1-4x}}{2x}$, so the given sum is $1$.

Comment: J.G. Thank you for your quick response, I appreciate it.  Your reference is a very straightforward approach, though I'm also curious if there might be other ways to show the series converges?

Comment: Answer doesn't look right.  As $x\to 0$, series $\to 1$, while function $\to \infty$.

Comment: @herbsteinberg You are mistaken:$$\lim_{x\to0}\frac{1-\sqrt{1-4x}}{2x}=\lim_{x\to0}\frac{2}{1+\sqrt{1-4x}}=1.$$

Comment: Sorry I hadn't look closely enough at the numerator.